# Strong difference between lambda.min and lambda.1se

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, small-sample

I have run an elastic net on a relatively small sample (n= 320) with 17 predictors and 5-fold cross-validation (no train-test sample because of the small sample size) and 100 bootstraps.

When I look at the predictions using the minimum lambda and alpha, I get a relatively full prediction table, with coefficients of various sizes. But when I use the criterion of within 1 SE of the minimum MSE, I get an empty predictor matrix.

Does this basically just mean my data is too bad/ unreliable to use for this analysis? If yes, where can I go from here? It's data from a hard-to-recruit sample, so it is already quite a lot for that specific group and I don't have an option of collecting more data for now as I'm under time-constraints.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The 1 SE lambda rule is just a rule of thumb, there is no theoretical reason for choosing the 1 SE model over the min model. What these results might be suggesting is that your results could change a lot with slightly different inputs, but for now the min model seems to work best for your data.